# acquireTokenSilent fails due to the blockage of third-party cookies

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

I am using MSAL.js for Azure ADB2C login. We are using Angular 7 and "@azure/msal-angular": "^0.1.2".
In some versions of safari and chrome browsers, acquireTokenSilent is failing and giving error

> AADB2C90077: User does not have an existing session and request prompt parameter has a value of 'None'.

Because of it failure its calling acquireTokenPopup so again the user want to login.
I found out that the issue is related to this settings of safari. If we change like this
Preferences -> Privacy -> Prevent cross-site tracking, it will solve the problem but its not a solution.
Is it useful If I update MSAL library? or any other solution for this? Pls help me and thanks in advance

Comment: We are working on releasing MSAL.js with auth code PKCE flow which will solve this as it doesn’t rely on cookies. Only solution right now is to use another library.

Comment: Can you mention other library which I can use ADB2C sign in  policy in my angular project?

Comment: Try [this](https://dev.to/kdhttps/the-best-security-for-single-page-applications-spa-openid-connect-oauth-2-0-authorization-code-pkce-flow-544p)

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Do you have any idea when we can use MSAL-2.0 in angular.is that relased?